# Calling GET Web API call after DELETE Web API has finished in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Here is my code:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the contact?")) {
    this.http.delete(this.apiRoot + id)
        .subscribe()

    this.loadContacts()
        .subscribe(); 
}
```

Tried lots of things but basically I want the Web API method to return before calling loadContacts()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "wait" until the delete request finishes you can use the `switchMap` RxJS operator.

```js
this.http.delete(this.apiRoot + id).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
        return this.loadContacts();
    })
).subscribe();
```

This will switch to the inner observable, when the outer one emits a value. More info can be [found on the Learn RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) site.